# Retrieved null when there is data in firestore with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app's profile page that is supposed to retrieve data from firestore and show them in editable textfield or date picker or whatever.

It turns out the snapshot.data seems not to be null, but the field it gets is null when there is actually data in my firestore.

Here is my code:

```
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initInfo();
  }

  initInfo() async {
    // get info from current user
    final currUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (currUser != null) {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc('Dv7DkLm6Ls8Q4tKuVXEq')
          .get();

      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
      name = data['name'];
      profilePath = data['profilePath'];
      birthday = data['birthday'].toDate();
      anniversary = data['annversary'].toDate();
      couple = data['couple'];

      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

The error is like:
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDate' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: toDate()

#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)

#1      _UserPageState.initInfo

And my firebase is like:
[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGafH.jpg)

Comment: May be your **data['birthday']** or **data['annversary']** null, Please check those data in logs!

Comment: Is the error in line `anniversary = data['annversary'].toDate();`? Because, you misspelled the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var birthday;
var anniversary;

  birthday = data['birthday'].toDate() ?? DateTime.now();
  anniversary = data['annversary'].toDate() ?? DateTime.now();
```

1st you need to check `birthday`,`anniversary` variable type make it as var . not string or DateTime ,

Comment: I changed them to var and tried to print them out but they are still null for some reason. The error now becomes: Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: never mind, it solved with changing the variables to late final variableName;

Answer (score 0):

Can you just check what data you are getting in the data map with the help of log(data.toString()) or print(data.toString()).

Comment: I did print(data.toString()) and everything was printed correctly. It somehow turns out data['xxx'] are all null